# fullcalendar: format events with same time

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar

In the weekAgenda view of fullcalendar 2 events starting at the same time are displayed like that:

```
+--------+--------+
|        |        |
|        |        |
|        +--------+
|             |
|             |
|             |
+-------------+
```

So you see, the left one is much wider than the right one. I want them to have the same width. Like that:

```
+--------+--------+
|        |        |
|        |        |
|        +--------+
|        |
|        |
|        |
+--------+
```

How can I do that?

Comment: can you provide the html code please? and css, if necessary. thank you.

Comment: Simon, the calendar widget I'm using here is [this one](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/). In order to use it, there's only one line of HTML, `<div id='calendar'></div>`, but of course a bunch of js. On their site it says that using a css file for the calendar is obsolete. Instead there are only some attributes that you can set in the js part, so I use:`height: 680, eventBackgroundColor: '#fff',  eventBorderColor: '#888'`. However, there don't seem to be any attributes for changing the looks of 2 parallel events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `slotEventOverlap: false` option in your instance.

Docs: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotEventOverlap